# Unable to declare fields of embedded struct in go

Tags: go

Within a `go` package named `kubesecretsPkg` I declare the following two struct types:

```golang
type KubesecretsOpts struct {
    FullPathToRepo string
    FullPathToApp  string
}

type KubesecretsSetOpts struct {
    KubesecretsOpts
    Variable string
    Value    string
}
```

I am trying to initialise an outer (`KubesecretsSetOpts`) in another package as follows:

```golang
        kSetOpts := kubesecretsPkg.KubesecretsSetOpts{
            kubesecretsPkg.KubesecretsOpts: {
                FullPathToRepo: fullPathToRepo,
                FullPathToApp:  fullPathToApp,
            },
            Variable: variable,
            Value:    value,
        }
```

this fails as follows:

[image]

Why am I not able to directly initialise an embedded struct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right syntax would be

```
   kSetOpts := kubesecretsPkg.KubesecretsSetOpts{
        KubesecretsOpts: kubesecretsPkg.KubesecretsOpts{
            FullPathToRepo: fullPathToRepo,
            FullPathToApp:  fullPathToApp,
        },
        Variable: variable,
        Value:    value,
    }
```

name of the field in the struct is "KubesecretsOpts" even in this scope however the ***type*** of the field is kubesecretsPkg.KubesecretsOpts. You are getting "invalid field name" error due to former fact in this scope.